# AjaxControlToolkit TabContainer with weird rendering behavior

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've built a web application that contains a page that uses the AjaxControlToolkit's TabContainer/TabPanel objects. I've developed a custom stylesheet, as well. I'm developing using Visual Studio 2010. The following is the behavior of my application:

**VS2010 Development Server (localhost:XXXXX):** Works as expected with the custom stylesheet.

**Local IIS:** The TabContainer rendered but the stylesheet wasn't applied. I fixed this by doing a CTRL+F5. It seems that IIS caches stylesheets pretty aggressively.

**Remote Server:** The TabContainer and TabPanel are completely hidden. Looking at the HTML, all of them have their visibility set to hidden.

The way I got my files onto my remote server were as follows (I haven't yet set up WebDAV or remote publishing because the server is a Windows 7 box and as far as I am aware does not support FrontPage Extensions):

*The entire solution is under source code control (SVN).*

1. Checked in all pending changes (including projects, aspx files, css, AjaxControlToolkit binaries)
2. Synced on the server.
3. Rebuilt everything on server.
4. Deployed to local IIS on server (which is externally accessible).

Both on the local IIS on the server and the development server on the server, the TabContainers are completely hidden. Looking at the SVN status on the server project, only the "AjaxControlToolkit.dll" is under source-code control. All the locale-specific DLLs are not on the server. Could this be a potential issue?

I'm not sure what's going on and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was strange. I was setting the visibility of the active TabPanel to false programmatically in my code-behind. For some reason, on my development machine this didn't cause any problems but in the server machine, it did.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are using the latest version of the toolkit? I had a visibility issue with the tabs the last time I upgraded a VS08 project to VS10.
Getting the latest version fixed that problem

Edit: Do you use the AjaxToolskriptManager or just the ScriptManager. You probably need the Ajaxone for most controls?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the latest version of the toolkit yesterday. My solution was upgraded to VS2010 before I even created a website project. The website project was created before I installed the ACT.

Do I need to change anything on the IIS management?

Comment: Usually you don't need to. The dll of ACT will be deployment with your webapplication project. It should be inside the bin directory.